# this.props.navigation.goBack() not working in DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Ok, let's make this straight. I am new in 'react-native'/'react-navigation'.

I've two screens, let's say A and B.It's wrapped under a `DrawerNavigator`. The screen `A` is the `initialRoute`, and when a button clicks from `A`, it navigates to `B` using `this.props.navigation.navigate('B');`, but when i try to `goBack` from B using `this.props.navigation.goBack()`. It doesn't work.

I've googled a lot, but couldn't find anything helpful. Why it's not working ? Am i missing something?

```
const HomeDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    A: A,
    B: B,
}, {
    initialRouteName : 'A'
});
```

Comment: Try A as StackA(StackNavigator) and B as StackB(StackNavigator).

Comment: You mean `StackNaviator` with single screen ?

Comment: Yes, try stack navigator with a single screen.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a perfect solution. Is there alternative ?

Comment: `this.props.navigation.navigate('B')` works. but `goBack()` should work no ?

Comment: If you have only screens in drawer navigator then `goBack()` not work, because screens are not in a stack. If you use Android then test android back button, If you are in Screen B and press back button you will navigate to Screen A. This is because DrawerNavigator has `backBehavior` property.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the **backBehavior** to **'initialRoute'**

```
const HomeDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    A: A,
    B: B, }, 
    {
    initialRouteName : 'A' 
    backBehavior: 'initialRoute',/* Add this line to your code*/
});
```